# Possible to upgrade Windows Server 2012 to R2 via Windows Update?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-update

I'm pretty sure this is not possible but just wanted to check. Windows Server 2012 R2 is basically a totally separate release right? I can't update R1 to R2 via Windows Update can I?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't update R1 to R2 via Windows Update can I?

No. No, you can't.

Also, it's not named Windows Server 2012 R1, it's just Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I know that it is not called R1, but it is easier to type. Sorry if my shorthand annoys you. I have avoided contractions in this comment so as not to trigger you, lol. ;)

Comment: I wasn't annoyed, I was just pointing it out. How typing 2 extra characters is easier than not typing them at all IS something that bewilders me though. ;)

Comment: I know. Just friendly banter :) I think if you look at where I wrote R1 and how the sentence reads with those 2 letters removed then it will begin to make sense though :D

Comment: No worries. I was playing along.